# Is there a way to subtract one array from another in kotlin

Tags: arrays, kotlin

I would like to subtract one `IntArray` from another in the most efficient way, for example `(3,3,2)` minus `(1,2,4)` to get `(2,1,-2)` as output. I tried doing `while` loops, but for some reason it just didn´t do anything (im pretty new to kotlin/programming). This is what I tried:

```
var firstArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,3)
var secondArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(4,4,1)
var differ: IntArray = intArrayOf(0,0,0)

fun difference(){
    var i = 0
    while (i < 3) {
        differ[i] = firstArray[i] - secondArray[i]
        i = i + 1
    }
}
```

I couldn´t find a correct syntax for kotlin. Any help is appreciated!

Comment: what do you mean by "it just didn't do anything"? if you call `difference()` it would calculate the difference of both... and set the values in `differ` accordingly... so your code isn't wrong... it's just not the most idiomatic/optimized one... the shortest other solution to your problem is just: `firstArray.zip(secondArray, Int::minus)` or `firstArray.zip(secondArray) { a, b -> a - b }` ... from there you can call: `toIntArray()` , `toTypedArray()`, `toList()` or just simply do `.forEach(::println)`

Answer (score 3):

You can use `zip` with `map` to achieve it

```
val differ = firstArray.zip(secondArray).map { el1, el2 ->
    el1 - el2
}
```

`zip` joins two arrays together, creating List of pairs of elements ([zip docs](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/zip.html)).

Comment: Cool thing... +1

Comment: note that you can use the overloaded zip-function to simplify it: `firstArray.zip(secondArray) { el1, el2 -> el1 - el2 }` or just `firstArray.zip(secondArray, Int::minus)`...

Answer (score 0):

Your method `difference` doesn't even have a return value…

If you want to subtract one array from another and do that index based for each element, then you should create a `fun` that takes two arguments, the minuend and the subtrahend, and has a return value, the resulting `IntArray`:

```
fun main() {
    var firstArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,3)
    var secondArray: IntArray = intArrayOf(4,4,1)

    // call the subtraction function
    val difference = subtract(firstArray, secondArray)

    // print the result
    for (i in difference) {
        print("$i ")
    }
}

fun subtract(minuend:IntArray, subtrahend:IntArray): IntArray {
    // check if both have same length and throw an Exception if not
    if (minuend.size != subtrahend.size) {
        throw RuntimeException("Cannot handle arrays of different size")
    } else {
        // then initialize an empty result array
        val result: IntArray = IntArray(minuend.size)

        // subtract the elements from another, index based
        for (i in 0..minuend.size - 1) {
            // and store the result in the corresponding index of the result array
            result[i] = minuend[i] - subtrahend[i]
        }

        // and finally return the result
        return result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly Array, but you can get IntArray

```
  val firstArray = arrayOf(1,2,3)
  val secondArray = arrayOf(1,1,1)
  val thirdArray:IntArray


  thirdArray=firstArray.zip(secondArray).map { it.first - it.second }.toIntArray()
  print("Diff ${thirdArray[0]} ${thirdArray[1]} ${thirdArray[2]} ")
```

Comment: you could also just call `toTypedArray()` instead... note that there exists an overloaded zip function that accepts a transform function directly, so you can skip that `map`-step...